# OpenGL ES2 GLubyte colors in vertex array not working

Tags: colors, shader, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-array

Apple suggests using the GLubyte data type for color data on iOS, so I am trying to get this to work. The result I get is that all color components <255 are completely black, and only components of colors set to 255 really are that color.

What I am doing:
-Save the color of a single object in my own Color class in GLubytes (range 0-255)
-Pass the colors to the shader in a vertex attribute array with type GLubyte (still range 0-255)
-In the fragment shader, use the color directly or divide components by 255, both do not work.

EDIT: this does work, the problem was somewhere else in my code.

Comment: If using generic attributes, make sure you set the normalized flag in `glVertexAttribPointer`, so your values get transformed to [0,1] automatically.

Comment: Passing colors as GLubytes in the range [0-255] and setting the normalized parameter to true yields the same results: still does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does just work fine, the problem was somewhere else in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Where does Apple recommend using `GLubyte` for vertex attributes? I think you have misinterpreted that hint. What you actually want to do is store those values in a 256x1 grayscale (`GL_LUMINANCE`) texture and pass it as a uniform to the shader. This would be indeed faster than using arrays.